# How to re-rewrite this backbone-related script to pass name of template/view to load

Tags: javascript, templates, optimization, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using Backbone.js and Underscore.js (as well as the usual suspects such as JQuery and require.js) to create a web application. Part of the web application's logic involves loading HTML views/templates. I had coded a mechanism (based on scripts found here and elsewhere) that looks like the following.

```
var some_View = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        initialize:function(){this.render();},
        render:function(){
                var renderedElement = this.$el.html(something.render("someView"));
            }

    }
)

var someView=new some_View( {el:$("#some_DIV_container")} );
```

Where **something.render("someView")** is a method that actually does the rendering. The method performs an AJAX call and essentially inserts the loaded results into the passed DIV (some_DIV_container) :

```
// code in the "something" object
render:function(tmpl_name,tmpl_data){
    console.log("loading view..." + tmpl_name);
    // this method renders a view. from the /views folder.
    if ( !this.render.tmpl_cache ) { 
        this.render.tmpl_cache = {};
    }
    if ( ! this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] ) {
        var tmpl_dir = 'views';
        var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + tmpl_name + '.html';
        var tmpl_string;
        $.ajax({
            url: tmpl_url,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType:'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                tmpl_string = data;
            }
        });
    this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);
    }
    console.log(" this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data) = "+ this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data));      
    return this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data);
}
```

The code works like a charm, except that every time I create a new view, I have to create some variable that extends Backbone.View, and create another variable that extends Backbone.View. In other words "someView", the name of the HTML file to load, is static. I would like to pass the name of the HTML template to load *dynamically*. I just can't see how I can pass the parameter the way some_View is written.

I think that (it appears)

- Backbone.View.Extend() returns some function object
- We use *el* to pass a jQuery reference to the container where we want to insert the HTML template/view code into
- when "some_View" is rendered, we call something.render, which loads and returns the HTML into the html() method of this.$el, which I believe is essentially the resolved div I want to insert the content into. The content gets inserted.

So in short, I want to optimize this code so that I don't have to repeat creating variables extending backbone.view.extend and instantiating it each time I want to create a view.

Any thoughts? It's a code puzzle!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to re-use the same view constructor for all your views? Seems like that will only work for very simple views that don't change or have user input.  But you might be able to do something like this, just pass in the template you want to use when you create a view.

```
var some_View = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        initialize:function(options){
            this.templateName = options.templateName;
            this.render();
        },
        render:function(){
                var renderedElement = this.$el.html(something.render(this.templateName));
            }

    }
)

var someView=new some_View( {el:$("#some_DIV_container"), templateName: 'someTemplate'} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant code that I used. (I also used Base.js to make a class)

```
// this method is part of a javascript class called qq

var qq = Base.extend({

///other stuff///

render:function(tmpl_name,tmpl_data){
    console.log(" render(): rendering view " + tmpl_name + ".html");

    if ( !this.render.tmpl_cache ) { 
        this.render.tmpl_cache = {};
    }
    if ( ! this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] ) {
        var tmpl_dir = 'views'; // your directory
        var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + tmpl_name + '.html';
        var tmpl_string;
        $.ajax({
            url: tmpl_url,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType:'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                tmpl_string = data;
            }
        });
    this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);
    }

    return this.render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data);
}

});


var q=new qq(); // where the method above comes from
// define some initial parameters

q.viewParams={
    initialize:function(options){console.log("viewName = "+this.options.viewName);this.renderIt();},
    renderIt:function(){
        var renderedEl= this.$el.html(q.render(this.options.viewName));
        } 
    };

// load the recipient view
var x = Backbone.View.extend( q.viewParams );
q.recipientView = new x( {el:q.recipientBoxEl,viewName:"someView"}  );
```